# Django apps on Heroku: how to access a shared database

Tags: django, database, heroku

On Heroku, it is possible to share a database among apps using [the following command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons#using-the-command-line-interface-attaching-an-add-on-to-another-app):

```
$ heroku addons:attach <databaseName> -a <appName>
```

where `<databaseName>` is the shared database (belonging to another app) and it is attached to the app `<appName>` (a Django application).

I googled around for a long time but couldn't find anything describing how to access the attached database in the app. Do I need to add or modify something to Django's `settings.py` and what? How do I access the attached database in Django's `views.py`?

The following is the setting for Heroku databases and database accessing is just via ORM.

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default':dj_database_url.config()}
# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: But Heroku says "the credentials are not permanent", so we are not supposed to specify directly the NAME, ENGINE, USER, PASSWORD, etc., in the `settings.py`.

Comment: The problem is actually adding one more item in the `DATABASES` dictionary, e.g., `DATABASES = {'default':dj_database_url.config(), 'course':???}`  and what should replace the `???`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku always supplies configuration details as environment variables. When you do `addons:attach` it will print the name of the variable it has created for your attached add-on; alternatively you can specify it with the `--as` flag.

```
heroku addons:attach <databaseName> -a <appName> --as MY_ATTACHED_DB_URL
```

Now you can pass that variable name to the `config` call:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':dj_database_url.config(),
    'course': dj_database_url.config('MY_ATTACHED_DB_URL')
}
```

Comment: However, I seemed to get an empty config: `'course': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'NAME': '', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}} `

Comment: Found the problem: it is required to add `_URL` to the connection string. For example, if I used `--as MY_ATTACHED_DB_URL` in the heroku `attach` command, then the connection string argument in `.config()` should be `MY_ATTACHED_DB_URL_URL`. Quite strange!

Comment: BTW, in order for a database to be shared between two apps, both apps have to have the exact same model definition. Is that correct?